# Availability/Upgradeability of Wildcard Module for Sitecore 8+

Tags: sitecore-marketplace, wildcards

I'm trying to get hold of a version of the Wildcard Module for Sitecore 8.1. Unfortunately the version on the Marketplace (https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Wildcard_module.aspx) only goes up to v6.5.

Is there a version of the Wildcard Module that is updated for Sitecore 8 or above? or an alternative option to use for Wildcards with Sitecore 8+?

How can I use wildcards with Sitecore 8+?

Comment: I'm note sure why this has been closed as it is relevant to 8.1 and might be useful for others.

Comment: I agree, I actually need to implement the wildcard module in Sitecore 8.1, so I'm trying the suggested answer below. This isn't off-topic at all.

Comment: Ken - I think it's possible to vote to re-open this so please do so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This one supports 8.0+ https://marketplace.sitecore.net/SearchResults#qr=helpfullcore - it works similar to the original Wildcard module, but doesn't use the rules engine to process the tokens.

You can view the documentation on it here: https://vladimirhil.com/2016/02/22/wildcards-module-for-sitecore-7-using-content-search-api/

Comment: Thanks Richard. In the mean time I've ended up implementing this using IIS url re-writes as I only needed to re-write a single url

/offers/details?guid=1412252&feedname=London

TO:

/offers/details/London/1258944

I'm using a custom page template with a custom component to actually get the data in need from an Xml feed so this all works fine. If I do decide to go with a wildcard solution in future though then i'll be sure to look at this in more detail as it looks great.